# keeps skipping prompts even after adding a space in front of %c

Tags: c, scanf

According to most of the sources and questions i have seen about the same issue i have tried adding space like so "scanf(" %c", &variable);" but for some reason it ended up skipping even more prompts that were suppose to be entered by the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Ic[12];
int contact[10];

void MainM();
void CustomerPortfolioMenu();
void IndustrialCommoditiesPricingMenu();
void NewCustomer();
void PickIndCom();

int main(void)
{
    char menu,CNA,customerPortMenu, industrialComPricing, firstN, lastN,email;
    
    MainM();

    printf("Enter your choice: \n");
    scanf("%c",&menu);
    
    system("cls");
    
    switch(menu)
    {
        case '1':
            CustomerPortfolioMenu();
            break;
        
        case '2':
            IndustrialCommoditiesPricingMenu();
            break;
            
        case '3':
            printf("Program Terminated");
            return 0;
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}


void MainM()
{
printf("     -Main Menu-     \n");
printf("1. Customer Portfolio\n");
printf("2. Industrial Commodities Pricing\n");
printf("3. Exit\n");
}

void CustomerPortfolioMenu()
{
    char customerPortMenu;
    printf("-Customer Portfolio Menu-\n");
            printf("1. New Customer Portfolio\n");
            printf("2. Existing Customer Portfolio\n");
            printf("3. Update Customer Portfolio\n");
            printf("4. Closed/Delete Customer Portfolio\n");
            printf("5. Return to Main menu\n");
            
            printf("Enter your choice: \n");
            scanf(" %c",&customerPortMenu);
            
            switch(customerPortMenu)
            {
                case '1': 
                NewCustomer();
                break;
            }
}

void IndustrialCommoditiesPricingMenu()
{
    char industrialComPricing;
printf("-Industrial Commodities Pricing Menu-\n");
            printf("1. Daily Industrial Metal Pricing\n");
            printf("2. Update Industrial Metal Pricing\n");
            printf("3. Return to Main Menu\n");
            
            printf("Enter your choice: \n");
            scanf(" %c",&industrialComPricing);
            
                        
            switch(industrialComPricing)
            {
                case '1':
                    NewCustomer();
                    break;
                }   
}
```

This is the part where the main issues usually happends after adding space to the first %c which is the one that prompts first name it will run but it would skip last name and end on Email address for some reason.

```
void NewCustomer()
{
    char firstN[10], lastN[10],email[50],address[100],CNA;
    int Ic,contact;
    printf("Enter First Name:\n");
    scanf(" %c",&firstN);
    printf("Enter Last Name:\n");
    scanf("%c",&lastN);
    printf("Enter I/C No:\n");
    scanf("%d",&Ic);
    printf("Enter Address:\n");
    scanf("%c",address);
    printf("Enter Contact No:\n");
    scanf("%d",&contact);
    printf("Enter email address:\n");
    scanf("%c",&email);
    printf("Create New Account (Y/N)?:\n");
    scanf("%c",&CNA);
}
```

Comment: What is your exact input? You try to scan "First Name" into a single character! That's kind of strange. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Firther, there are several places where you are using `%c` without a leading space

Comment: Unrelated: Having a global variable named `contact` and a local variable named `contact` is bad style.

Comment: those are just placeholders for now cause i'll be changing those but for now it keeps skipping over prompts that i have inserted like it would let me input first name but then skip last name and goes straight into I/C number

Comment: As said, it is getting a *single character* for first and last names. So if you enter `Jason` for the first name, then `firstN == 'J'` and `lastN == 'a'`. And so on.

Comment: oh ok i see what you mean thank for that but weirdly for some reason it's still skipping my prompts and ending on address also from changing that i also found that for some reason when i input 3 characters it will jump to the address input skipping both I/C and last name

Comment: @Jason You still haven't told us the exact input! What do you type in the terminal?

Comment: oh sorry just keep enter 1 twice in each menu to get there

Comment: Ok so I finally asked a friend about it and apparently I should be using %s instead of %c and it instantly solved my issues. XD